# "Couldn't resolve resource" in Android Studio's Preview

Tags: android, android-studio

After adding new items in `strings.xml`, quite often they don't start working immediately in Android Studio's Preview.

> Couldn't resolve resource @string/faq_customer_service

Preview looks like this:

[image]

I've obviously tried to re-build the project, and even run `gradle clean assembleDebug`, but it doesn't seem to help. On emulator & real device the newly-added string resources do work.

Any trick to force Android Studio to reload the resources so that the correct texts show up in Preview?

Answer (score 172, accepted):

The only reliable way I've found so far is reloading the project / restarting Android Studio.

Quickest way to do that is **File → Invalidate caches / Restart... → Just Restart**.

Feel free to post better solutions!

Answer (score 12):

you DO NOT need to close the entire project. It's just way too much for so little problem.

Just refresh the preview (click the "refresh" button)
[image: refresh button arrow]

provided from https://stackoverflow.com/a/34754707/3339597

Comment: and if it doesn't work, try building the project (Ctrl+F9) and then pressing the refresh button.

Comment: Thanx! It's helped me when I trying to use vector graphic! +1

Comment: This button was removed in Android Studio 2.3. And now the only choice is to reload the whole IDE... anybody knows how to bring the button back? Amazing when companies just think refresh is not necessary.

Answer (score 6):

Right click on project and Synchronize '...Project' worked for me.

Comment: Cool, thanks. Although now, with Android Studio 0.3.1, the problem seems to be fixed; Preview immediately shows the changes in `strings.xml`, even without Synchronize.

Comment: Actually, now that I was running into Preview problems again, Synchronize did nothing for me, but Restart helped.

Comment: After synchronizing do not forget to refresh the preview!

Answer (score 0):

There are three steps for solving this problem

1. **Build -->Clean Project**
2. **Build -->Rebuild Project**
3. Restart android studio

Comment: Seems a lot quicker just to restart Android Studio

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't resolve resource @string/faq_customer_service
or
Couldn't resolve resource @id/visible 
or
Couldn't resolve resource @id/masked 
The solution is if you implement TextInputLayout the above problems may arise ... so Simply add those id or strings to xml files as their property.

Answer (score 0):

**Render Problem**:

```
Couldn't resolve resource @string/hello_blank_fragment
```

Just refresh the Layout.

work for me..