# Rendering Problems @id/visible Android Studio

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-studio

I have [this](https://1drv.ms/w/s!AniEkQ5k9-XDnDY-LGDwStXyAwoe) xml file. If I compile it works fine, but if I go to see the preview it shows me this error:

[image]

I tried to look for this id but I couldn't find it anywhere.
What is this @id/visible? How can I fix that?
Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Couldn't resolve resource" in Android Studio's Preview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19429948/couldnt-resolve-resource-in-android-studios-preview)

Comment: @Charuka, no, it's a bug of appcompat-v7:25.1.0 as written in accepted answer and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41303347/couldnt-resolve-resource-id-visible-when-using-textinputlayout.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Couldn't resolve resource @id/visible when using TextInputLayout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41303347/couldnt-resolve-resource-id-visible-when-using-textinputlayout)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The error likely originated from `android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout`. If so, it (most likely) is a bug, and it has been [filed in the Issue Tracker](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=230766).

To test if `android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout` is the culprit, remove them from your layout and see if the error still persists.

If so, you may try to switch the API version in the editor to 19 or below, though [you may see some minor differences in the design output](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=230766#c5). Or simply remove `android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout` until the issue has been solved.

Answer (score 6):

This is not the solution but I have added these lines to dimens.xml:

```
<resources>
    <item name="visible" type="id"/>
    <item name="masked" type="id"/>
</resources>
```

Comment: Hey better than nothing.

Comment: Perfect, worked like charm. Tried all other options Restart, Clean, Change API all failed. By adding these 2 lines fixed my issue...

Answer (score 2):

The real reason for this is because you have a `LinearLayout` inside of a `ConstraintLayout`. Try to change all `LinearLayouts` to Constrained ones and the problem will go away

Comment: I don't have a ConstraintLayout in a project. Maybe Navigation drawer affects. But API 19 works.

Answer (score 1):

try invalidating cache

File → Invalidate caches / Restart... → Just Restart.

Answer (score 0):

You should set 
1. android:id="@+id/visible" to android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout and 2. android:id="@+id/masked" to child of TextInputLayout

Answer (score 0):

just add two line cod in strings.xml file Then clean project  `

```
  <item name="visible" type="id"/>
  <item name="masked" type="id"/>`
```

Because Android studio can not understand the type of attribute of some libraries like 'TextInputLayout '
And by doing this, we'll tell Android Studio that attribute visible  is id type